# What is the fastest way to get only directory list

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to build a tree structure recursively of **only** directories for a given root/parent path. <strike>something like "browse for folder" dialog.</strike>

Delphi's `FindFirst` ([`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) API) is not working with `faDirectory` and `FindNext` will get all files (it uses `faAnyFile` regardless of the specified `faDirectory`) not only directories. which make the process of building the tree  *very* slow.

Is there a fast way to get a directory list (tree) without using `FindFirst`/`FindNext`?

Comment: If you don't want to write a low level driver, maybe you can take a look how .NET does this task in the `Directory.GetDirectories` method. But I bet they operate there with `FindFirstFile` function.

Comment: more fast way use `FindFirstFileEx` however the most fast use `NtQueryDirectoryFile` with `FileDirectoryInformation`. you got files and folders in any case, but you can easy filter it by `dwFileAttributes`

Comment: option return only directories not exist - but you can minimize number of calls by using `NtQueryDirectoryFile` (all can be done in single call if buffer large enough) (with `FindFirstFileEx` will be how minimum 2 calls) and you can select different info classes - less info - more speed.

Comment: Doesn't delphi have a "shell tree view" control you could just use?

Comment: @Victoria - this is absolute false. this is both user mode and kernel mode api. if you have zero knowledge about this - not need say

Comment: TDirectory.GetDirectories works fine for me

Comment: @DaveNottage, how is it implemented? and "fine" is very relative :) `FindFirstFile/Ex` also works "fine" but it also enumerates files, not only directories.

Comment: @zett42, Delphi  has "shell tree view" but I don't want to use it. I should not have mentioned the "browse for folder" dialog. I just need a fast way to get all directories under some parent directory.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291797/efficiently-list-all-sub-directories-in-a-directory

Comment: @zig 1. You could try it - for me, it returns directories only. It also has the option of retrieving all subdirectories. 2. You could read the source if you have Pro or above to find out whether it uses FindFirst etc

Comment: @DaveNottage, unfortunately I only have Delphi 7 at hand. that is why I asked how it was implemented.

Comment: @zig It uses FindFirst. In future, please specify the version of Delphi in your question.

Comment: @DaveNottage, Sorry about that. in the initial question I did specified `Delphi-7` tag. You can see that @Remy addresses that in his answer. I then **assumed** newer version also use `FindFirst` (No magic here apparently) so I removed the version tag. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Did you try profiling to find the heavy part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the absolute fastest way, use the [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) api. with this we can query not single file but many files at once. also select what information will be returned (smaller info - higher speed). example (with full recursion)

```
// int nLevel, PSTR prefix for debug only
void ntTraverse(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa, int nLevel, PSTR prefix)
{
    enum { ALLOCSIZE = 0x10000 };//64kb

    if (nLevel > MAXUCHAR)
    {
        DbgPrint("nLevel > MAXUCHAR\n");
        return ;
    }

    NTSTATUS status;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName };

    DbgPrint("%s[<%wZ>]\n", prefix, poa->ObjectName);

    if (0 <= (status = NtOpenFile(&oa.RootDirectory, FILE_GENERIC_READ, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT)))
    {
        if (PVOID buffer = new UCHAR[ALLOCSIZE])
        {
            union {
                PVOID pv;
                PBYTE pb;
                PFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION DirInfo;
            };

            while (0 <= (status = NtQueryDirectoryFile(oa.RootDirectory, NULL, NULL, NULL, &iosb, 
                pv = buffer, ALLOCSIZE, FileDirectoryInformation, 0, NULL, FALSE)))
            {

                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    ObjectName.Buffer = DirInfo->FileName;

                    switch (ObjectName.Length = (USHORT)DirInfo->FileNameLength)
                    {
                    case 2*sizeof(WCHAR):
                        if (ObjectName.Buffer[1] != '.') break;
                    case sizeof(WCHAR):
                        if (ObjectName.Buffer[0] == '.') continue;
                    }

                    ObjectName.MaximumLength = ObjectName.Length;

                    if (DirInfo->FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                    {
                        ntTraverse(&oa, nLevel + 1, prefix - 1);
                    }

                } while (NextEntryOffset = DirInfo->NextEntryOffset);    
            }

            delete [] buffer;

            if (status == STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES)
            {
                status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }
        }

        NtClose(oa.RootDirectory);
    }

    if (0 > status)
    {
        DbgPrint("---- %x %wZ\n", status, poa->ObjectName);
    }
}
   


void ntTraverse()
{
    BOOLEAN b;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);

    char prefix[MAXUCHAR + 1];
    memset(prefix, '\t', MAXUCHAR);
    prefix[MAXUCHAR] = 0;

    STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "\\systemroot");
    ntTraverse(&oa, 0, prefix + MAXUCHAR);
}
```

but if you use interactive tree - you not need expand all tree at once, but only top level, handle `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` with `TVE_EXPAND` and `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` with `TVE_COLLAPSE` for expand/ collapse nodes on user click and set `cChildren`

if use `FindFirstFileExW` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` and `FindExInfoBasic` this give to as near `NtQueryDirectoryFile` perfomance, but little smaller:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
HANDLE hFindFile = FindFirstFileExW(L"..\\*", FindExInfoBasic, &fd, FindExSearchLimitToDirectories, 0, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);
if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do 
    {
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (fd.cFileName[0] == '.')
            {
                switch (fd.cFileName[1])
                {
                case 0:
                    continue;
                case '.':
                    if (fd.cFileName[2] == 0) continue;
                    break;
                }
            }
            DbgPrint("%S\n", fd.cFileName);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, &fd));

    FindClose(hFindFile);
}
```

unfortunately `FindExSearchLimitToDirectories` not implemented currently

Comment: I'm giving up on this idea completely. I need to rethink about returning the *entire* directory tree. I did not found any *drastic* improvements for any of the methods. maybe accessing the filesystem metadata directly will do the trick, but I'm just not built for it...Thanks.

Comment: @zig - are you try at once enum all directory tree - or on user request (if this is gui app - tree view) - if you expand only 1 level deep - all must work very well. why Nt or Ex method is faster - with `FindFirstFile` - you need N+1 call to fs driver if folder containing N files - every call need switch context user/kernel/user, allocate Irp, an FS driver need a lot of synchronization before access folder for return to us .. single file. this is very expensive. when we use big enough buffer - we can do this call only once - and buffer will be filled with N files. this must have effect

Comment: I have not fully tested `NtQueryDirectoryFile` (only started translating today -  most of the NT headers are missing in Delphi7) but I take your word for it. when I have more time next week I will try and actually profile it v.s `FindFirstFileEx`

Comment: Regarding the UI with TreeView for example, The problem with expanding 1 level deep is that you don't know in advance if the directory has children (you can click on the node and then query if it has children but I think it's ugly) so You need a 2 level deep recursion to determine if a directory has children to display the expanders (`+` buttons). and then drill down when item is expanded with 2 level deep again) But I really needed this for a web service returning all directories in all levels to the client.

Comment: or make a function like `IsDirHasChildDirectories` which will *again* enumerate all (in some cases) files/directories of parent directory just to determine if it has child directory. I was under the impression that `FileFirstFile` will always give directories first, before files so this check could be optimized, but it is not the case.

Comment: @zig - first time you need set `cChildren` to `I_CHILDRENCALLBACK` and handle `TVN_GETDISPINFO`. when you first time got `mask & TVIF_CHILDREN` - only at this time query - are children exist and set `cChildren` to 0 or 1. this already serious improve performance on big folders - only visible items got this request. really if all correct written - must be very fast; say on my windows 10 function which i paste enumerate all `\\windows` less than 4 second (without dbgprint)

Comment: @zig - also `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` and got `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` - this is optional - in case you normal can not open some folder due security. you can remove this flag. and about `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` - with this flag - you not expand mount/reparse point (i paste this from code which delete folder - here this need) in case you want expand and enter to mount points - remove this flag

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable information. I did not know about `I_CHILDRENCALLBACK`. I will try it.

Comment: @zig - [`I_CHILDRENCALLBACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773518(v=vs.85).aspx) give huge advantage in folders like `"\windows\WinSxS"` where huge count of subfolder - you not need just enumerate all, but only which receive `mask & TVIF_CHILDREN` (current visible only). i implement this on registry tree (here bit easy - exactly exist info - are key have subkeys). if you correct implement next : `<TVN_GETDISPINFO>`, `<TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, TVE_EXPAND>` (expand node) `<TVN_ITEMEXPANDED, TVE_COLLAPSE>` (collapse node) `<TVN_DELETEITEM>` - all must work well (win Nt*)

Comment: BTW, `indows 10 function which i paste enumerate all \\windows less than 4 second` - 4 seconds is a very very long time for my task even if other methods will take twice as that (I do understand that `\windows\WinSxS` is huge). But I can't predict the magnitude on each customer server. this is why I drooped this idea completely and my web-service will return directory list level by level

Comment: @zig - you not understand - 4 second - this is **full enumeration** (full recursion, any level) with all subfolders. you need only one level deep. - will be absolute another result

Comment: I do understand that it is with all sub folders. This was my initial task: to return `full enumeration with all subfolders`. As I said, I will not be using full enumeration. and will be using one level deep as you suggested.

Comment: yes, with only one level deep (+ extra 1 level for visible items (for handle `I_CHILDRENCALLBACK`)) - will be absolute another result. very fast.

Comment: @conio - this is fastest way for get information via file system. if you want parse MFT directly - try it. if you know how do this, how convert line mft  struct to directory tree. (so you in general need read all records) etc. get MFT records directly more suitable when we need got list of all files, and not care about child/parent hierarchy

Comment: @RbMm: I don't know. There are libraries whose writers do know.

Comment: @conio i think touch MFT not best way and not very suitable when need display files in tree view. way with `NtQueryDirectoryFile` or `FindFirstFileExW` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` enough and give good permanence if correctly implemented UI. the `FindFirstFile` much more bad by perfomance

Comment: @conio - main - need minimize count of calls to FS on folder. `FindFirstFile` use N+1 calls (where N count of files - very worst). `FindFirstFileExW` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` use how minimum (and usual) 3 calls. with `NtQueryDirectoryFile` and optimization for predict `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES` - usual 1 call only. and very important correctly implement UI

Answer (score 7):

`Find(First|Next)/File()` is a viable solution, especially in Delphi 7. Just filter out the results you don't need, eg:

```
if FindFirst(Root, faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
try
  repeat
    if (sr.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) and (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
    begin
      // ... 
    end;
  until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
finally
  FindClose(sr);
end;
```

If that is not fast enough for you, then other options include:

1. On Win7+, use [`FindFirstFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419.aspx) with `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH`. That will provide speed improvements over `FindFirstFile()`.
2. access the filesystem metadata directly. On NTFS, you can use [`DeviceIoControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216.aspx) to enumerate the [Master File Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230.aspx) directly.

Comment: I have done this, and this is exactly what I don't want to do. `FindFirst` with `faDirectory` does not finds only directories but any file. so even if you filter it will take for ever. Windows explorer sees to show the directory tree in no time.

Comment: `which has some speed improvements over FindFirstFile()` - really speed improvements not small on big folders - because `FindFirstFile` return only single file per call. so n files in folder - n calls. `FindFirstFileEx()` - can return group of files at once - how many fit to buffer (now if not mistake 64kb) but any way it do how minimum 2 calls to kernel. possible with Nt version have and single call have and use large buffer - all this very serious speed up perfomance

Comment: @zig - `Windows explorer sees to show the directory tree in no time` - because explorer expand only current level. and next level on click. not try enumerate all at once. may be you try just build all tree, but not enumerate new node only on user action

Comment: What about [`FindExSearchLimitToDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364416.aspx) for parameter `fSearchOp` of `FindFirstFileEx()`? Doc states it is an "advisory" flag, but it could be a worth a try.

Comment: @RbMm, I see what you mean,  I also tried expanding levels one by one, so I did a single recursion only, just to know if the directory has child directories or not. it works much better. the thing is I have a requirement to return the entire directory list from a web-service. so I'm focusing on that now.

Comment: @zig - no problem 10 min

Comment: @Remy, I don't think `FindExInfoBasic` is even implemented. or the headers are wrong. there is almost zero improvement for `FindFirstFileEx` with any flag I tried including `FindExSearchLimitToDirectories`. I'll will keep on trying. Thanks.

Comment: @zig - `FindExInfoBasic` implemented begin from some windows version, but most improvement give to us `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` flag

Comment: @zett42: read the documentation for `FindExSearchLimitToDirectories`. It is only an advisory flag, not guaranteed to be supported on all systems, so you still have to be prepared to filter out non-directory entries manually.

Comment: @RbMm: `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` were both added in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Remy What makes you think I didn't read the docs? I even posted a link to it. Say this the flag would help improving performance on at least some of the systems, wouldn't you like to use it? I'm not saying it does anything, but it is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Delphi XE2 or newer, the fastest way is to use the `TDirectory.GetDirectories` defined in th `System.IOUtils`.

Sample code:

```
procedure TVideoCamera.GetInterfaceNameList(
  const AInterfaceNameList: TInterfaceNameList);
const
  SEARCH_OPTION = TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
  PREDICATE = nil;
var
  interfaceList: TStringDynArray;
  idxInterface: Integer;
  interfaceName: String;
begin
  interfaceList := TDirectory.GetDirectories(GetCameraDirectory, SEARCH_OPTION,
      PREDICATE);

  AInterfaceNameList.Clear;
  for idxInterface := Low(interfaceList) to High(interfaceList) do
  begin
    interfaceName := ExtractFileName(InterfaceList[idxInterface]);
    AInterfaceNameList.Add(interfaceName);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Looking at the implementation of this function, I *seriously* doubt this is the fastest way. You do know that "fastest" in this Q is about runtime performance?

Comment: Okay, I do not know it. The `TDirectory` is using FindFirst/FindNext methods - that were not considered here precisely as slow - and supports exactly the feature that was asked here.